# Regex to replace marker {{MARKER}} in string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a problem with regex to replace `{{MARKER}}` value.

```
String baseString = "any string with marker {{TEST_MARKER}} here";
String key = "TEST_MARKER";
String val = "123";
String pattern = String.format("\\{\\{%s\\}\\}", key);
String result = baseString.replaceAll(pattern, val);
```

It works correctly for any `baseString`. But I get an exception in one case. If `baseString` contains `${some_text}`.

So I will get an error If I use something like this:

```
String baseString = "any string ${test} with marker {{TEST_MARKER}} here";
```

Result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No group with name {test}
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1059) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:997) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2939) ~[na:na]
```

or:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1051) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:997) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2939) ~[na:na]
```

It depends on base string. How to fix this?

Comment: Using your code, I got the following results: `any string with marker 123 here`,
`any string ${test} with marker 123 here`.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is 'use `Pattern.QUOTE` - you don't want `key` to be interpreted as regex-relevant'.

However, that's still a silly way to go about. Why do you think you need regular expressions here? You.. do not.

Just use `.replace` (which replaces ALL occurrences; `.replaceAll` interprets the first arg as a regex, and is in contrast to `.replaceFirst` which also interprets the first arg as a regex but only replaces the first occurrence. Yes, these are badly named methods. `replace` replaces all and does not interpret, which is what you want). By avoiding regular expressions, you avoid some exotic Denial of Service attack surface and it's faster in general, too.

```
String baseString = "any string with marker {{TEST_MARKER}} here. Just to prove the point, {{TEST_MARKER}} again.";
String key = "TEST_MARKER";
String val = "123";
String pattern = String.format("\\{\\{%s\\}\\}", key);
String result = baseString.replace(pattern, val);
```

Or, possibly, look into [mustache](https://www.baeldung.com/mustache) - a library that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, you're right, I don't need a regex, replace() method is enough.